# How to send app update notifications in private app "store"?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, web

I have a webpage which lists the links to .apk files for android applications which users can download. Is there a way to send upgrade notifications to people who have downloaded a certain app and I reupload that app to the server? I have tried to find how Apple keeps track of the devices that have downloaded an app off the appstore but can't find anything. How would I keep track of devices that download a certain app and then send a notification to them whenever I reupload that app(update it)? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Everytime an app starts, make a call to that store and check if an update is available.

Comment: Wow, never thought of that. thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, that's the way I implemented it in my company.

Comment: Very cool technique. Do you know of any way to send push notifications to the user when the app isn't already on? So the user can know the app has been updated as soon the new update is out.

Comment: Yes I do. Whenever the app checks for the update, include the pushId. When a new update is added to the store, send a push notification to all the logged PushId's.

Comment: You can use a service ready to do it. PushLink helps your app keep itself updated. Take a look at https://www.push-link.com.